# How to write a complex number in terms of a complex base.

Tags: complex-numbers

When dealing with real numbers, we can easily write a integer $ X $ easily in terms of base $ Y $.
$$ X= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k Y^k $$
where $0 <=a_k <Y $,
The conversion is easy by a simple algorithm but how can we do the same for complex numbers?

Comment: Even for positive integers $X$ and $Y$, that's not true: you need to allow $a_k = 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79092/14578

Answer (score -1):

You do it just the same for the real and imaginary parts separately.  When you write $z=a+bi$ you can express $a$ and $b$ however you want.

Comment: But if I do it separately, then it will be of the form $ Re (X)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_r Re (Y)^k $ and $ Im (X)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_i Im (Y)^k $ which on adding will not give $ X=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k Y^k $

Comment: Why do you have the factor $k$ in there?  I think you need braces around the subscripts.  You should have $ar_k$ and $ai_k$ for the real and imaginary parts.  Then $X=Re(X)+iIm(X)$ just fine.

Comment: That's fine but the right hand side will not be in the terms of power of Y.

Comment: It is two power series in $Y$.  You can then put the reals and imaginaries together if you insist and have $\sum [(ar_k)+(iai_k)]Y^k$  I would rather have $123_9+456_9i$ than $(1+4i)9^2+(2+5i)9+(3+6i)$

Comment: But if $ Y $ is complex, then what are the methods to compute the $ Re(X) $ and $ Im (X) $ in terms of powers of $ Y $. Also, I intend to have the $ a_k $ real such $0 <=a_k <|Y|$.

Comment: I didn’t understand that you wanted Y to be complex. Even in the reals we insist that the base be an integer, and rarely accept negative ones. We can represent reals that way. Why do you want complex bases?

Comment: Actually, this question is inspired by this problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/CODE1/